# std::bind with pointer to a function object

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, shared-ptr, variadic-templates

Given a pointer to a function object:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::function<double(double)>> f;
```

is there a built-in construct in C++11 that allows be to use this pointer in a `std::bind` statement? For example:

```
std::function<double()> g = std::bind(built_in(f), 0.0);
```

What I am doing is to use *variadic template* as:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::function<Ret(Args...)> get_fn(const std::shared_ptr<std::function<Ret(Args...)>>& f)
{
    return [=](Args... args) -> Ret { return (*f)(args...); };
}
```

This allows me to write:

```
std::function<double()> g = std::bind(get_fn(f), 0.0);
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I should have been clearer. I need to use the instance of the function object inside the shared pointer for optimization purposes.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe The built-in command in the language that I am looking for, but it seems there is not such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we had a Standard function object for the dereference operator (much like `std::plus<T>` is for adding `T` with `T`) then we could involve a nested bind expression, but that is not the case -- plus we'd need a call operator because the usual substitutions that take place during the evaluation of nested bind expressions don't apply to the first argument! Your solution introduces an additional `std::function`, so I'm proposing some alternatives that don't.

Write your own call and dereference operators:

```
struct call {
    template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Callable&& callable, Args&&... args) const
    // don't use std::result_of
    -> decltype( std::declval<Callable>()(std::declval<Args>()...) )
    { return std::forward<Callable>(callable)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

struct dereference {
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T&& t) const
    -> decltype( *std::declval<T>() )
    { return *std::forward<T>(t); }
};

template<typename IndirectCallable, typename... Args>
auto indirect_bind(IndirectCallable&& f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( std::bind(call {}
                       , std::bind(dereference {}, std::declval<IndirectCallable>())
                       , std::declval<Args>()... ) )
{ return std::bind(call {}
                   , std::bind(dereference {}, std::forward<IndirectCallable>(f))
                   , std::forward<Args>()... ); }
```

You can then do `auto g = indirect_bind(f, 0.0);`. [Here's a proof-of-concept](http://liveworkspace.org/code/fadb6b6d4072bfa60a50f92f7bcbdcdb) that also shows how placeholders are appropriately dealt with.

I mention the above solution because functors like `call` and `dereference` are useful bricks -- I personally have them among my tools. My preferred solution however would be to write a polymorphic functor that does the indirection and call in one go:

```
template<typename Indirect>
struct indirect_callable_type {
    // Encapsulation left as an exercise
    Indirect f;

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    // don't use std::result_of
    -> decltype( std::declval<Indirect&>()(std::declval<Args>()...) )
    { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    // don't use std::result_of
    -> decltype( std::declval<Indirect const&>()(std::declval<Args>()...) )
    { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    // Lvalue and rvalue *this version also left as an exercise
};

template<typename T>
indirect_callable_type<typename std::decay<T>::type>
make_indirect_callable(T&& t)
{ return { std::forward<T>(t) }; }
```

which you can, in fact, use as `auto g = std::bind(make_indirect_callable(f), 0.0);`.

I should mention that unlike your solution, those requires writing some types out-of-line. This is an unfortunate situation due to the inherent limitations of lambda expressions. Should you wish to stick with what you currently have, I have a minor recommendation that inside the lambda you `std::forward<Args>(args)...` the parameters. This might prove useful if you ever deal with move-only types.

Comment: Could you please show me how your suggestion on the `std::forward<Args>(args)...` would fit in my approach?

Comment: @Allan In the return statement inside the lambda.

Comment: Like this `return [=](Args... args) -> Ret { return (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };` you mean. A new world to be discovered now with C++11.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice little hack you can use here, which is that *`INVOKE`*  on a pointer to member function automatically indirects its object argument when passed a pointer or (even) a smart pointer (20.8.2p1 second bullet, definition of *`INVOKE`*):

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<double(double)>> f
        = std::make_shared<std::function<double(double)>>(
            [](double d) { return d + 10.0; });
    std::function<double()> g = std::bind(
        &std::function<double(double)>::operator(), f, 0.0);
    std::cout << g() << std::endl;
}
```

If you don't want to mention explicitly the type of `f`:

```
std::function<double()> g = std::bind(
    &std::remove_reference<decltype(*f)>::type::operator(), f, 0.0);
```

Comment: Interesting; I knew `std::men_fn`, but what was concerning me was the need to state the function type, which can be quite long. Your second approach, which avoids the explicit declaration of the function type is better in my opinion.

Comment: @Allan I was searching my head trying to remember which facility performs the automatic indirection; I found it in `mem_fn` but then discovered you don't even need to use `mem_fn`; a `bind` is enough!

Comment: If we write `std::bind(f, 0.0)`, I believe the result type cannot be cast to `std::function<double()>`. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Although `std::bind(f, 0.0)` works, it does not result in a function type convertible to `std::function<double()>`. This is a simplification of my real case, of course, where a predefined function type exists and the result of the _bind_ operation needs to conform to it.

Comment: @Allan `std::bind` is non-strict; almost anything will appear to work.  It won't check whether the bind actually makes sense until you try to call it (or convert it to `std::function`, which is pretty much the same thing).  That's why you have to use `&std::remove_reference<decltype(*f)>::type::operator()`, even if `mem_fn` isn't required.